# How to show fontawesome icons in admin page inside Ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I managed to insert fontawesome iconS using Ckeditor with the [Font Awesome Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) v1 module.

I just put this code in the HTML view of Ckeditor.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg">&nbsp;</i>
```

The icon is shown correctly in frontend but in CKEditor it is not shown at all.

I guess I need to load all fontawesome files inside Ckeditor. How can I do this? I need to see the icon in ckeditor in the same way as I see it in frontend.

Fontawesome is located at: **sites/all/libraries/fontawesome**

Comment: Is fontawesome implemented in the backend? For the backend theme?

Comment: @leymannx I just enabled the fontawesome module, I think it not implemented in backend. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

A [CKEditor plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/fontawesome) for fontawesome exists. If you're using the [WYSIWYG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) there are a number of hooks that allows you to modify your WYSIWYG editor. In fact, someone has done a write up on how to manually add [CKEditor plugins using Drupal](http://margotskapacs.com/2014/05/adding-ckeditor-plugins-manually-in-drupal/).

Comment: The tutorial works fine to install the Leaflet plugin. But is not that easy for the Fontawesome plugin.

Comment: What's the problem with the CKEditor plugin?

Comment: the icon is not shown at all under Editor appearance/Available buttons

Comment: Update: the icon is SHOWN under Editor appearance/Available buttons. I drag it to the Toolbar. But the icon is not shown when editing a page.

Answer (score 2):

I use the add-on [CKEditor Font Awesome](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-font-awesome/index.html) by DOKSoft. This plugin will attach Font Awesome CSS automatically. See [demo](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-font-awesome/demo.html).

Comment: Unfortunately that is a non-free add-on.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Font-Awesome icons in the Drupal wysiwyg area as well. Add the following line in the wysiwyg advanced options > Custom JavaScript config. (admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/xxx):

```
config.contentsCss = ['//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootswatch/3.3.6/readable/bootstrap.css'];
```

ps: you may like to add this second line to allow empty tag (then you can avoid the useless`&nbsp;` in the  tag)

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;
```

At the end  you should have something similar to:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;
config.contentsCss = ['//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootswatch/3.3.6/readable/bootstrap.css'];
```